# Google Classroom API: Upload file to "class drive folder" but ensure only teacher can see it

Tags: google-classroom

I am using the Google Classroom API to allow students to take tests using our system and send the overall grades back up. That is all working fine.

What I want to do is to create a spreadsheet of the breakdown of student results from our system and upload that either as a CSV or create a Google Spreadsheet. This spreadsheet *should only be visible to the teacher(s) of the course*.

Is it possible to create a Google Spreadsheet / Drive file which is *only visible to the teacher*. I was thinking to put it in the course [driveFolder](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/DriveFolder) but it's not clear to me what the permissions are of that folder. For example, the entire folder could be shared with students and so obviously I don't want to put the results there as they shouldn't be visible to students.

Another possibility might be to upload it to the teachers *own* drive account, but, that doesn't seem ideal either.

My absolute preference would be to attach it to the "courseWork" item in some teacher-only-visible way, but, it doesn't look like that's an option.

Anyway, sorry for the slightly wooly question, but, if you're doing something like this and have a suggestion I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `teacherFolder` from the [course resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#resource-course) refers to:

> a [DriveFolder](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/DriveFolder) that is shared with all teachers of the course.

This folder is created when the course itself is created, and by default it is shared with course teachers but **not with students**, so I think it would be the perfect place to store the spreadsheet. Storing data that is only shared with teachers is this folder's purpose, anyway.

#### Update: Prevent editors from changing access permissions:

In order to avoid the risk of a folder being shared, the owner of the folder can prevent editors from changing access permissions and sharing the folder with other accounts. Just click the **Share** button and, in **Advanced** options, check the **Prevent editors from changing access and adding new people** box, as explained [here](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308868?hl=en).

Of course, the folder owner can still invite new people and change these settings, so I'd suggest you to transfer ownership to a safe account that you are sure 100% won't try to share this folder with students.

#### Reference:

- [Classroom API: Courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#resource-course)
- [Restrict sharing options on Drive files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308868)

Comment: Yip, I know it's for `teachers of the course`, however, can you guarantee that's the case (without probably pulling back the permissions of the underlying folder and trying to work out who it has been shared with?). I agree though that it does seem like the right place, it's just the risk of putting sensitive content in there seems high!

Comment: I just test shared the `teacherFolder` with a student account: it was allowed. So, if I did put content in there then it would have been shared with that student.  I agree 99 times out of 100 the teacher is *not* going to share the folder, but, that one time could be bad and it's what I want to protect against.

Comment: @patrickdavey You can prevent editors to share the folder with other people. I updated my answer with that. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I'll mark it as correct :) What I'm really looking for is a way to do that via the API, I'll just have to play with it (for the beta version, we might just put it in the folder with a message telling the teacher where we're going to put it..). Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @patrickdavey Unfortunately I think this cannot be done via API. The property that manage this, [capabilities](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#capabilities), is read-only: this can only be done through the UI.